# Question about if else statements in bash

Tags: bash, x-dwm

I'm attempting to write a function for dwmbar in bash using playerctl to return metadata about a song.

If there is nothing playing, e.g. if `playerctl status` returns `No players found`. I want it to show nothing.

The example below however prints metadata at all times.

What have I done wrong?

[EDITED]

```bash
mpd() {
  PS=$(2>/dev/null playerctl status)

  echo "$(date): ${PS}" >> debug.log
 
  if ! [[ "${PS}" =~ ".*No play.*" ]];then  
      MD=$(2>/dev/null playerctl metadata --format '{{uc(artist) }}|{{uc(title)}}')
      TITLE=$(echo ${MD} | cut -d'|' -f 1)
      ARTIST=$(echo ${MD} | cut -d '|' -f 2)

      printf "^c$pink^ ^c$blue^${TITLE}"
      printf "^c$pink^${ARTIST}^c$blue^ "
    else    
      # Do you really need a space printed here?
      printf " "
      # Do you really need to exit from inside a function?
      exit 0 
    fi
}
```

(Prior post)

```bash
mpd() {
  PS=$(2>/dev/null playerctl status)

  echo "$(date): ${PS}" >> debug.log

  if [[ ${PS} == "No players available" ]];then          
      printf "^c$pink^ ^c$blue^$(playerctl metadata --format '{{ uc(artist) }}') "
      printf "^c$pink^$(playerctl metadata --format '{{ uc(title) }}')^c$blue^ "
    else    
      # Do you really need a space printed here?
      printf " "
      # Do you really need to exit from inside a function?
      exit 0 
    fi
}
```

Edit: this works

```
mpd() {
PS=$(2>/dev/null playerctl status)
NP='No players'

  if [[ "$PS" == *"$NP"* ]]; then
    printf " "
  else
    printf "^c$pink^ ^c$blue^$(playerctl metadata --format '{{ uc(artist) }}') "
    printf "^c$pink^$(playerctl metadata --format '{{ uc(title) }}')^c$blue^ "

  fi
}
```

Comment: If `playerctl` outputs stuff on stderr, you can get rid of it by redirecting that to `/dev/null` like this: `$(playerctl status 2> /dev/null)`.

Comment: Are the asterisks in `*"No players"*` really in the script?

Comment: I'd recommend putting `set -x` at the beginning of the function to turn on execution tracing (and `set +x` at then end to turn it off), and see what bash thinks is happening as it runs.

Comment: My guess is your comparison of [[ ${player_status} == "No Players Available" ]] is failing every time as the EXACT text "No Players Available" never appears.  I suggest making it more imprecise, e.g.  [[ ${player_status}== "No Pl"* ]].

Comment: @Ted Lyngomo:   * In the compare makes it a wildcard compare.  The [[ is a BASH compare so adds features over sh.  The bash man page is horrid, but this page helps: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-check-if-string-contains-substring-in-bash/

Comment: I've edited your code to help you find out what you should be comparing.

Comment: Bash's regex parser treats quoted characters as literal rather than RE metacharacters, so with `[[ "${PS}" =~ ".*No play.*" ]]` it's looking for literal periods and asterisks in the string. You could use just `[[ "${PS}" =~ "No play" ]]` since RE patterns are not anchored by default (i.e. it searches for a matching *substring*, not necessarily a whole-string match). But also, please clarify the exact result you're getting from `playerctl status`.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
mpd() {
PS=$(2>/dev/null playerctl status)
NP='No players'

  if [[ "$PS" == *"$NP"* ]]; then
    printf " "
  else
    printf "^c$pink^ ^c$blue^$(playerctl metadata --format '{{ uc(artist) }}') "
    printf "^c$pink^$(playerctl metadata --format '{{ uc(title) }}')^c$blue^ "

  fi
}
```